# What is HeaderFile in Doxygen?

Tags: latex, doxygen, header-files

I run this command unsuccessufully

```
doxygen -w latex headerFile styleSheetFile project.doxy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen will produce LaTeX output if you set `GENERATE_LATEX=YES` in your doxygen configuration file.

The command you quoted instructs doxygen to write its default LaTeX document header and stylesheet to files, so this should have created two  files, named `headerFile` and `styleSheetFile`. This is explained in the doxygen documentation [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/doxygen_usage.html).

You can then use the `LATEX_HEADER` option in your configuration file to tell doxygen to use your header file instead of its default, and this allows you to customise the style of the document. `LATEX_HEADER` is described [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_latex_header).